# How to change the drop down values dynamically

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I am new to Bokeh and need some help please. I am trying change the drop-down-1 box values dynamically based on other drop-down-2 box selection. I looked at Bokeh examples but cant find one. Here is the code that I am messing around.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(server_list=["old_value_1", "old_value_2"]))

def update():
    tech_val = tech.value
    if tech_val == 'art':
        source.data = dict(
            server_list=["new_value_1", "new_value_2"]
        )
#         servers.update()

env = Select(title="Environment", value="PROD", options=["DEV", "QA", "PROD"])
tech = Select(title="Subject Area", value="science", options=["science", "art"])

servers = Select(title="Server", options=source.data['server_list'])
controls = [env, tech, servers]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

sizing_mode = 'fixed'

inputs = widgetbox(*controls, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)
l = layout([[inputs]], sizing_mode=sizing_mode)
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example which will change the options displayed in the Environment drop down depending on which value is selected in the Subject area drop down.

If you also want the values to change you can just use the same approach.

This should allow you to change values and options of drop downs dynamically.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column,row, widgetbox,layout
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import (Select)
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(server_list=["old_value_1", "old_value_2"]))

def update(attrname, old, new):
    tval = tech.value
    env.options = env_dict[tval]

tech_options = ["science", "art"]
env_options1  = ["DEV", "QA", "PROD"]
env_options2 = ["DEV2", "QA2", "PROD2"]
env_dict = dict(zip(tech_options,[env_options1, env_options2]))
env = Select(title="Environment", value="PROD", options=["DEV", "QA", "PROD"])
tech = Select(title="Subject Area", value="science", options=tech_options)

servers = Select(title="Server", options=source.data['server_list'])

""" update drop down 1 based off drop down 2 values """
tech.on_change("value", update)

sizing_mode = 'fixed'

inputs = widgetbox([env,tech,servers], sizing_mode=sizing_mode)
l = layout([[inputs]], sizing_mode=sizing_mode)
curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Sliders"
```